# Highlight specific character or words coming from solr result

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to highlight the only word or character which is searched by user. The search result is coming from solr is fine but if user typed R then all word Rahul is being highlighted but i want to highlight only 'R'.

For this I am using this code:

```
solrQuery.setHighlight(true)
solrQuery.addHighlightField("*")
solrQuery.setHighlightSimplePre("<span class='highlight-bg'>")
solrQuery.setHighlightSimplePost("</span>")
```

Solr version:4.7.2

Comment: Can you share your schema file?